# Cannot convert 'Class::operator==' from type 'bool (Class::)(Class*) to type 'bool

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, equality-operator

I'm doing a method to see if two cards have same number or suit

This are my overload operators and my method where I call the overload operator

```
bool Carta::operator==(Carta *c){
   if(getNumCarta()==c->getNumCarta() || getNumPal()==c->getNumPal()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    //return(numCarta==c->numCarta)||(numPal!==c->numPal);
}

bool Carta::operator!=(Carta *c){
    if(getNumCarta()!=c->getNumCarta() && getNumPal()!=c->getNumPal()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool Table::pairs(){

    for(int i=1;i<posFull;i++){

        if(t[i-1]->operator == t[i+1]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I expect to return a true but never happen

Comment: Voting to close as typo. It's `t[i-1]->operator==(t[i+1])` if you really want to stick with explicitly calling the operator. Or, more conventionally, `*t[i-1] == t[i+1]`. (Even more conventional would be to not take a pointer but a reference, so that the operator is symmetric: `*t[i-1] == *t[i+1]`).

Comment: Further, `if (x) return true; else return false;` is simply `return x;`.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. And what's the difference between first and second?

Comment: Readability... and in the obove functions, make it `function(const Carta* c) const` since you are not going to change lhs or rhs

Comment: @MaxLanghof what u mean in if(x) return true;... In the overload operator?

Comment: @Lluis implicit conversion: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: Instead of `if(getNumCarta()!=c->getNumCarta() && getNumPal()!=c->getNumPal()){ return true; } else { return false; }` - just do:

`return getNumCarta() != c->getNumCarta() && getNumPal() != c->getNumPal();`

Comment: @Lluis You calculate a boolean expression within the `if (...)`. If that expression is `true`, you return `true`. If it's `false`, you return `false`. It's pointless to introduce an `if` statement for this. I can't put multi-line code here. But consider `bool x = ...; if (x == true) return true; else return false;` and how it is just a more convoluted way of writing `return x;`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you mean

```
if(t[i-1]->operator ==( t[i+1]) ){
```

Or you could write

```
if( *t[i-1] == t[i+1] ){
```

However this operator declaration

```
bool operator==(Carta *c);
```

only confuses readers of the code. It would be better to declare the operator like

```
bool operator ==( const Carta &c ) const;
```

and use it like

```
if( *t[i-1] == *t[i+1] ){
```